# Closed sets in infinite product topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

> For each $I\in\mathbb{N}$ let $C_i$ be a closed subset of a topological space $(X_i\tau_i)$. Prove that $\prod_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}C_i$ is a closed subset of $\prod_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}(X_i,\tau_i)$.

$\prod_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}(X_i,\tau_i)\setminus\prod_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}C_i=\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_\limits{i=1}^{\infty} (X_i\setminus C_i)$ since the union of open sets is open.

**Question:**

Is this reasoning acceptable for infinite product topological spaces?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Double use of $i$! Plus an infinite product of sets $X\setminus C_i$ is open in the box topology but not in general in the product topology.

Comment: That is something hard for me to understand. Why are the product of open sets not open in the infinite product topology?

Comment: Because they don't contain a basic open subset which is non-trivial at finitely many coordinates only. So they cannot be a union of basic open sets.

Comment: Sorry but I am not understanding the comment. Please could you explained in a little more detail?

Comment: Do you know the standard base for the product topology?

Comment: Yes I do. The product of open sets of the topologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87646/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-pedro-gomes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula makes no sense because of the two conflicting $i$ indices.

We can correct it as follows (for arbitrary index set):

$$\prod_{i \in I} X_i \setminus \prod_{i \in I} C_i = \bigcup_{j\in I} \prod_{i \in I} O(i,j)$$ where $O(i,j) = X_i$ for $i \neq j$ and $O(i,j) = X_j \setminus C_j$ for $i=j$. We could write that product of $O(i,j)$ for fixed $j$ as $\pi_j^{-1}[X_j \setminus C_j]$ as well.

This holds as $f \notin \prod_{i \in I} C_i$ iff there exists some $j$ such that $f(j) \notin C_j$.

At any rate, the complement of $\prod_i C_i$ is writeable as a union of products of (sub)basic open sets and hence open.